# How to redirect complete output of a cron script

Tags: python, shell, cron

I have a simple cronjob running every day at 18:35:

```
05 18 * * * ~/job.sh 2>&1 >> ~/job.log
```

So the output of ~/job.sh should be written into ~/job.log. In job.sh, there are some echo commands and a few python scripts are executed, e.g.:

```
echo 'doing xyz'
python doXYZ.py
```

Now, whatever output the python scripts produce, they are not written into ~/job.log. I only see the echo text in ~/job.log. How can I redirect the *complete* output of the shell script to ~/job.log?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Arkaitz has the simplest solution. However, to see what's wrong with your snippet we need to go into the bash manual:

> Note that the order of redirections is significant.  For  example,  the
>   command
>
> ```
>   ls > dirlist 2>&1
> ```
>
> directs  both  standard  output and standard error to the file dirlist,
>   while the command
>
> ```
>  ls 2>&1 > dirlist
> ```
>
> directs only the standard output to file dirlist, because the  standard
>   error  was duplicated from the standard output before the standard out‐
>   put was redirected to dirlist.

So apparently the output redirection only redirects to the *target* of the other stream, not to the other stream itself. When bash parses your command line it will come upon the `2>&1` clause and redirect `stderr` to the target of `stdout`, which at this point is still the console (or whatever is attached to `cron`'s `stdout`). Only after this will `stdout` be redirected.

So what you really want is:

```
05 18 * * * ~/job.sh >>~/job.log 2>&1
```

Comment: @musicinmybrain: not really, I had the exact same problem a couple of days ago. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `~/job.sh &>> ~/job.log` ?

Comment: &>> does not produce any output at all.
&> produces the correct output. However, it doesn't append, it overwrites!

How can I let it append the new output to the old content?

Comment: It does append to the file

Answer (score 2):

You need to redirect the output of the python script. Learning Python 2nd Edition recommends the following:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('log.txt', 'a')   # Redirects output to file
...
print x, y, x                       # shows up in log.txt
```

and goes on to say:

> "Here, we reset `sys.stdout` to a maually-opened output file object opened in append mode. After the reset, every `print` statement anywhere in the program will write its text to the end of file `log.txt.` instead of the original output stream."

Comment: This would work for the python scripts but is a not so elegant solution because one needs to specify the file name of the log both in the python script and in the cronjob. 

Also, if I need to redirect the output of other commands that are in "job.sh" (say there's a "git commit -a -m 'auto-commit'" in it) this won't help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure that this should work in a general case. The stdout file descriptor is changed by the OS when you use shell redirection.

However, if your Python script itself directly writes to the screen (perhaps by opening /dev/tty), it won't get captured in your log.txt. Is that the case? Does it fail even for a simple python program that just does a

```
print "Hello"
```

?

Comment: Yes, even a simple python script with nothing but this print line doesn't write to the log. The problem was the order of redirection (see wds' answer).