# How to redirect cron job output to stdout

Tags: linux, unix, cron

I have a cron job and its output is now redirected into a file. It looks like the following

`0 9 * * * /bin/sh /bin/cleanup.sh > /home/darkknight/cleanup.log`

Can any one help me to rediect its output to stdout?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to redirect complete output of a script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887618/how-to-redirect-complete-output-of-a-script)

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52330/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-from-within-cron

Comment: `cron` is running in the background of the shell, so to which `stdout` you want it redirect the output to?

Comment: In my case I can enable debug log from a terminal. I want to set that terminal as stdout

Comment: @AvihooMamka: It's not running in the background *of the shell*. It's not associated with any shell.

Comment: That's probably not a sensible thing to do. What do you want to happen when you log out or quit your current shell process, and the cron job keeps running?

Comment: achoora's answer worked for me. In the case of shell exit, we will need to specify new terminal name if need the log again.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Running process has a PID and its fd (file descriptor) is mapping to `/proc/<PID>/fd`. And we can find PID of the running cron process at `/var/run/crond.pid`.

To send cron log to stdout, we could write log to fd number 1 of the process started by cron.

```
0 9 * * * /bin/sh /bin/cleanup.sh > /proc/$(cat /var/run/crond.pid)/fd/1 2>&1
```

Comment: How is that useful? On my system, for example, stdout and stderr of the `/usr/bin/cron` process are directed to sockets.

Comment: @KeithThompson My scenario is that I use a docker container running cron service (use `cron -f` make cron running at foreground), and since I want to collect logs for monitoring and analytics. According to 12 factor app - `Treat logs as event streams` so I redirect cron log to stdout.

Comment: Does that actually work? Are you able to access data written to those sockets?

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, it works for me at debian:jessie. I don't access the sockets directly (haven't try it.), but using `docker logs` and fluentd.

Comment: It crosses my mind that for the docker scenario it is more accurate to specify `procid=1` : `/proc/1/fd/1 2>&1` because proc 1 is what goes out to docker logs

Comment: How can you then tail this? Because if I try `tail -f $(/proc/$(cat /var/run/crond.pid)/fd/1)` I get permission denied

Comment: For `docker` you [don't need](https://gist.github.com/mowings/59790ae930accef486bfb9a417e9d446) `crond.pid`. And please make it clear that you provide a `docker`-only solution. Otherwise it's confusing.

Comment: @gaga5lala can u provide some code snippets of your solution? I have tried it for two days now, but cannot get it working.

Comment: Is it sufficient to use `>` when one wants to append and not overwrite in this case, or will that still overwrite previous logs? If it overwrites logs, could you add a note for other people, that one needs to choose between `>>` and `>`?

Answer (score 10):

Enter `tty` on any terminal and we will get device file for that particular teminal window like `/dev/pts/1`.  Redirct the cron job into this file as 
`cleanup.sh > /dev/pts/1`

Comment: That tty will become invalid (closed and perhaps later reused) when you log out or quit your current shell.

Comment: How can you tail this? Because using tail -f /dev/pts/1 will log: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3):

Run `cat /home/darkknight/cleanup.log` then you get the output on STDOUT.
If you can't see what you expect as output, maybe you need to modify the cron as following:

`0 9 * * * /bin/sh /bin/cleanup.sh > /home/darkknight/cleanup.log 2>&1`

To get what `cleanup.sh` writes on its STDERR.

If you don't want to lose the output of yesterday, modify as following:

`0 9 * * * /bin/sh /bin/cleanup.sh >> /home/darkknight/cleanup.log 2>&1`

Or, just execute `/bin/sh /bin/cleanup.sh` then you get both STDOUT and STDERR on your terminal.