# Docker ubuntu cron tail logs not visible

Tags: docker, logging, cron, docker-compose, tty

Trying to run a docker container that has a cron scheduling.  However I cannot make it output logs.

Im using docker-compose.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
---
version: '3'
services:
  cron:
    build:
      context: cron/
    container_name: ubuntu-cron
```

**cron/Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:18.10

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron 

ADD hello-cron /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

# Run the command on container startup
CMD cron && tail -F /var/log/cron.log
```

**cron/hello-cron**

```
* * * * * root echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

The above runs fine its outputting logs inside the container however they are not streamed to the docker.

e.g.
`docker logs -f ubuntu-cron` returns empty results

but

if you login to the container `docker exec -it -i ubuntu-cron /bin/bash` you have logs.

```
cat /var/log/cron.log 
Hello world
Hello world
Hello world
```

Now Im thinking that maybe I dont need to log to a file?  could attach this to sttoud but not sure how to do this.

This looks similar...
[How to redirect cron job output to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36441312/how-to-redirect-cron-job-output-to-stdout)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to some weirdness in the docker layers and inodes, you have to create the file during the CMD:

```
CMD cron && touch /var/log/cron.log && tail -F /var/log/cron.log
```

This works both for file and stdout:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.10

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron

ADD hello-cron /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
# Run the command on container startup
CMD cron && touch /var/log/cron.log && tail -F /var/log/cron.log
```

The explanation seems to be this one:

In the original post `tail` command starts "listening" to a file which is in a layer of the image, then when `cron` writes the first line to that file, docker copies the file to a new layer, the container layer (because of the nature of copy-and-write filesystem, the way that docker works). So when the file gets created in a new layer it gets a different inode and `tail` keeps listening in the previous state, so looses every update to the "new file". [Credits BMitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43802109/output-of-tail-f-at-the-end-of-a-docker-cmd-is-not-showing)

Comment: As this will not logrotate the cron.log file it may grow very large depending on your cron output..

Answer (score 7):

I tried your setup and the following Dockerfile works:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.10

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron

ADD hello-cron /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0755 /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

# Symlink the cron to stdout
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/cron.log

# Run the command on container startup
CMD cron && tail -F /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

Also note that I'm bringing the container up with "docker-compose up" rather than docker. It wouldn't matter in this particular example, but if your actual solution is bigger it might matter.

EDIT: Here's the output when I run docker-compose up:

```
neekoy@synchronoss:~$ sudo docker-compose up
Starting ubuntu-cron ... done
Attaching to ubuntu-cron
ubuntu-cron | Hello world
ubuntu-cron | Hello world
ubuntu-cron | Hello world
```

Same in the logs obviously:

```
neekoy@synchronoss:~$ sudo docker logs daf0ff73a640
Hello world
Hello world
Hello world
Hello world
Hello world
```

My understanding is that the above is the goal.

Comment: Doesnt work for me.  "RUN ln -sf" resutls in the file always being empty.  take that out and the logs are populated but they are not streamed to the docker compose output

Comment: @Robbo_UK In the OP it was mentioned that we don't need the output in a file. Let me know if you want it both in a file and in stdout.

Also, I made an edit to my post with output of stdout when I run the container.

Comment: output to sttdout is fine.  what does your hello-cron look like.

Comment: The same as yours. Basically just add that row I referenced and run "docker-compose up".

Comment: hmm its not working for me...  I do think that this is the correct answer.  Ive put it on github.  Must be something different that is missed?
https://github.com/davidsonr/docker-ubuntu-cron

Comment: For anyone using a debian derived docker image, you also need to make sure rsyslog is installed for the above answer to log things to /dev/stdout properly. So just append it to the install cron command like so `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron rsyslog`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to redirect on this `> /dev/stdout`, after this you should see your logs with a docker logs.

Comment: think this is on the right path.. However the ubuntu container exits.  May need something from here to keep it running

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775266/how-to-keep-docker-container-running-after-starting-services